# What is the meaning of prison guard words?

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Prisoner* trade *Guard* his gold watch for escaping from the place.

> First, You have to stop the generator, There will be darkness, may be
>   only ten minutes. That is your chance. you must wait until the **change
>   of the final watch**.

Is he referring to people who working for watch tower or anything else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Watch](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/watch) (n):
>
> 1. An act of guarding someone or something to make sure the person or property stays safe and in the right place: *The prison guards kept a close watch on him.*
>      ​
> 2. A period during which someone is responsible for guarding or looking around to be sure that property or people are safe, or the person who is responsible:
>      *The soldiers on the night watch had to be careful not to fall asleep.*

In your example, it's more the second definition.  Guard shifts would be divided up into different "watches", which change on a regular basis.  The "final watch" would be the last of these shifts.